# Object Attributes Getting Set Without Me Asking

Tags: perl, oop, object, moose

I'm using [`Moose`](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Moose-2.0604/lib/Moose.pm), maybe it matters, maybe it doesn't.

My object comes in as `$event`, and I save the `args` attribute value to a variable:

```
my $args = $event->args;
```

That value happens to be a hash, so I do some stuff to the hash, specifically adding a new element:

```
$$args{id} = 4;
```

Here's what I don't understand, when I go back to look at my `$event` object, it has that new hash element saved inside!  I set it to a completely different variable, not the object, so why does the object receive it?

Comment: Better as `$args->{id} = 4`

Comment: I'm not clear what difference you expected the assigment to make. If it doesn't modify the object somehow then what is it for? It is rarely a good idea to poke around the contents of an object. You should stick to the official interface as described in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get a little bit advanced, instead of doing

```
has 'args' => (
  is => 'rw',
  isa => 'HashRef',
);
```

or whatever you normally do, you can do something like

```
has '_args' => (
  is => 'ro',
  isa => 'HashRef',
  default => sub { +{} },
  traits => ['Hash'],
  handles => {
    args => 'kv', # or args => 'shallow_clone'
    set_arg => 'set',
    get_arg => 'get',
    clear_arg => 'delete',
  },
);
```

now, the args are still stored in the object as a hashref, but it's stored in a private attribute named `_args`, and you use other methods to access it, for example `my %args = $event->args` (if you used `kv`) or `my $args = $event->args` (if you used `shallow_clone`, you get a hashref, but it's still a copy), `$event->set_arg("foo" => "bar"); my $value = $event->get_arg("foo")` etc. This is strictly optional, and you should skip it if you don't understand it, but it helps you build a more orthogonal interface and hide implementation details from your users.

Comment: This does make sense, thank you.  I always thought setting a new variable with a hashref cloned the hash.

Answer (score 2):

Moose does not matter. `$event->args` returns you hash refence, so your copy and `$event->args` points to same hash.
When you add a key it will be added, so it visible from both references.

To avoid this, you can copy hash which is returned by `args`:

```
my $args = {%{$event->args}};
```

After copy you getting reference to new hash so `$args` becomes reference to copy, no other code change required.

Answer (score 1):

What you get back from `$event->args` is not a hash, but a hash *reference.* That is, it's a pointer to a hash which is also pointed to by the `args` attribute in your object. When you say `$$args{id} = 4` (or `$args->{id} = 4` which is equivalent) you're changing the value in the hash that `$args` points to. Since a pointer to that hash is also stored in your object, the change is reflected there as well.

If you want to change the stuff in `$args` without affecting the object, you can make a copy of the hash:

```
my %args = %{ $event->args };
```